# Jenkins Pipeline - how to prevent global pipeline updates from running jobs that use SCM polling?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been using Jenkins pipeline with a global pipeline library, and it's been awesome. The one problem I have with it is that for jobs that use SCM polling, any updates to the global pipeline library are picked up by polling and fire off a build. I don't want this to happen at all - I want the next build that runs to pick up the global pipeline updates when the build runs.

Is this possible?